# C# Cannot get dictionary key (string) from value (string[])

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that classifies animals in C# where you specify the kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus and species of an animal and the program outputs what animal it is.

I am using a dictionary to represent all of the animals with a `string animalType, string[] animalAttributes`

To get it to work, I need to be able to find the key of a dictionary for a given value, which I created a method for, but I keep getting an out of index error.

I have looked through a few posts already but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that solved this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**My Code**

**Animal.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Challenge_4___Classification
{
    class Animal
    {
        /* Propeties */

        public string AnimalType { get; private set; } = "none";
        private static Dictionary<string, string[]> AnimalDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        public string Kingdom { get; set; }
        public string Phylum { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
        public string Genus { get; set; }
        public string Species { get; set; }
        public string[] AnimalAttributes { get; set; } = new string[7];

        /****************************************************************************************/

        /* Constructors */

        public Animal(string kingdom, string phylum, string _class, string order, string family, string genus, string species )
        {
            Kingdom = kingdom;
            Phylum = phylum;
            Class = _class;
            Order = order;
            Family = family;
            Genus = genus;
            Species = species;

            SetAnimalAttirbutes();
            AddDomesticAnimals();
        }

        /****************************************************************************************/

        /* Methods */

        public void SetAnimalAttirbutes()
        {
            AnimalAttributes[0] = Kingdom;
            AnimalAttributes[1] = Phylum;
            AnimalAttributes[2] = Class;
            AnimalAttributes[3] = Order;
            AnimalAttributes[4] = Family;
            AnimalAttributes[5] = Genus;
            AnimalAttributes[6] = Species;
        }

        private void AddDomesticAnimals()
        {
            AnimalDictionary.Add("horse", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata" , "mammalia", "perissodactyla", "equidae", "equus", "ferus" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("cow", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "artiodactyla", "bovidae", "bos", "taurus" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("sheep", new string[7] { "animallia", "chordata", "mammalia", "artiodactyla", "bovidae", "ovis", "aries" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("pig", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "artiodactyla", "suidae", "sus", "scrofa" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("dog", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "carnivora", "canidae", "canis", "lupus" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("cat", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "carnivora", "felidae", "felis", "silvestris" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("lion", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "carnivora", "felidae", "panthera", "leo" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("tiger", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "carnivora", "felidae", "panthera", "tigris" });
            /*AnimalDictionary.Add("dolphin", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("seal", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("penguin", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("ostrich", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("sparrow", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("spider", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("ant", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("bee", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("wasp", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("termite", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("octopus", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("squid", new string[7] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } );*/
        }

        private void AddWhales()
        {
            // Aetiocetidae
                // Aetiocetus
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale1", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "aetiocetus", "cotylalveus" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale2", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "aetiocetus", "polydentatus" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale3", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "aetiocetus", "tomitai" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale4", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "aetiocetus", "weltoni" } );
                // Ashorocetus
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale5", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "ashorocetus", "eguchii" } );
                // Chonocetus
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale6", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "chonocetus", "sookensis" } );
                // Fucaia
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale7", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "fucaia", "buelli" } );
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale8", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "fucaia", "goedertorum" } );
                // Morawanocetus
            AnimalDictionary.Add("whale9", new string[7] { "animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "cetartiodactyla", "aetiocetidae", "morawanocetus", "yabukii" } );
        }



        public string GetDictionaryKey(string[] targetValue)
        {
            List<string[]> valuesList = new List<string[]>();
            List<string> keysList = new List<string>();

            var values = AnimalDictionary.Values;
            var keys = AnimalDictionary.Keys;


            foreach (string[] value in values)
            {
                valuesList.Add(value);
            }

            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                keysList.Add(key);
            }

            int valueIndex = valuesList.IndexOf(targetValue);

            return keysList[valueIndex];
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            if (AnimalDictionary.ContainsValue(AnimalAttributes))
            {
                AnimalType = GetDictionaryKey(AnimalAttributes);
            }
            else
            {
                AnimalType = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Program.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Challenge_4___Classification
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal dog = new Animal("animalia", "chordata", "mammalia", "carnivora", "canidae", "canis", "lupus");

            Console.WriteLine(dog.AnimalType);
            dog.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(dog.AnimalType);
            Console.WriteLine(dog.GetDictionaryKey(dog.AnimalAttributes));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger and see what happens at this code line when the exception is being thrown: `int valueIndex = valuesList.IndexOf(targetValue);` (Hint: Two different array object instances are not equal, even if they both contain the same elements in the same order. You would need to write a custom comparer for your arrays to make the list lookup work)

Comment: By the way, you don't really need to create temporary keysList and valuesList lists. Remember, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a collection of key-value-pairs: `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. So, instead of the dance with keysList and valuesLists, iterate over this collection (the dictionary) directly to find the key-value-pair which has the value you are looking for (you will still need to do you custom array comparer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are assuming that the instance on this line is the same which is not. The instance for `targetValue` is not the same as the one inserted in the `valuesList` even if the values are the same.

```
int valueIndex = valuesList.IndexOf(targetValue);
```

**Change to:**

```
public string GetDictionaryKey(string[] targetValue)
{
    List<string[]> valuesList = new List<string[]>();
    List<string> keysList = new List<string>();

    var values = AnimalDictionary.Values;
    var keys = AnimalDictionary.Keys;


    foreach (string[] value in values)
    {
        valuesList.Add(value);
    }

    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        keysList.Add(key);
    }

    var entry = values.FirstOrDefault(r => r.SequenceEqual(targetValue));

    int valueIndex = valuesList.IndexOf(entry);

    return keysList[valueIndex];
}
```

<strike>Note that arrays are reference types and not primitive types. Only primitive types can be directly used on the `.IndexOf` method when you are not working with the same variable instances.</strike>

> Arrays are mechanisms that allow you to treat several items as a
>   single collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)
>   supports single-dimensional arrays, multidimensional arrays, and
>   jagged arrays (arrays of arrays). All array types are implicitly
>   derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object.
>   This means that all arrays are always reference types which are
>   allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a
>   reference to the array and not the array itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985948.aspx

Comment: "_Only primitive types can be directly used on the .IndexOf method when you are not working with the same variable instances_" That is incorrect. The only thing that decides whether one can use IndexOf "directly" is whether the involved element types are equatable. Depending on the particular collection type on which IndexOf is executed, the specific definition of what constitutes equatable types might differ (as an example, see arrays vs. generic collections). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Also, many collection types accept some form of custom comparer, allowing to use IndexOf directly even if the element types involved are not equatable by themselves. Whether an element type is primitive or not is of little importance (examples: string is no primitive type, nor is a delegate type, yet both are equatable)

Comment: I stand corrected then. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. I'm not quite sure how it works though, can you explain it?

Comment: Based on your initial design, I used `.FirstOrDefault` to get the item instance from `values` with the same sequence (order) as the `targetValue` by making use of the `.SequenceEqual` method. After fetching the instance, it is then used as parameter in the `.IndexOf` which yields your desired result. Your initial problem is that `targetValue`'s instance is not the same with the one in `values` even when the elements are exactly the same which is why you were getting `-1` as `valueIndex` and an index out of bounds exception.